# how to check screen size of iphone 7 plus and iphone x programmatically in swift 4

Tags: swift

I need to replace this Objective-C to Swift 4. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to transfer it?

```
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && UIScreen.mainScreen.nativeBounds.size.height == 2436) {
          YSLContainerViewController *containerVC = [[YSLContainerViewController alloc]initWithControllers:@[controller1,controller2,controller3,controller4,controller5,controller6,controller7]
                                                                                                topBarHeight: 276
                                                                                        parentViewController:self];
            containerVC.delegate = self;
            containerVC.menuItemFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@".SFUIText-Medium" size:11];

            [self.view addSubview:containerVC.view];`enter code here`  
     }
```

Comment: How about `UIScreen.main.bounds.height`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.size.height == 2436 {
    var containerVC = YSLContainerViewController(controllers: [controller1, controller2, controller3, controller4, controller5, controller6, controller7], topBarHeight: 276, parentViewController: self)
    containerVC.delegate = self
    containerVC.menuItemFont = UIFont(name: ".SFUIText-Medium", size: 11)
    view.addSubview(containerVC.view)
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.0**

By this you can check the current device is iphoneX or not...

```
  func isIphoneX() -> Bool {
            let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
            let screenWidht = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width

            if (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.phone) {

                if ( screenHeight == 812 && screenWidht == 375) {
                    return true
                } else {
                    return false
                }
            }
            return false
        }
```